# merge two text file without common column in python

Tags: python, file, join

I have 2 text files with the same number of rows, but there is no common column between my files. the first file has 9 columns and the 2nd one has 8 columns. both of them have 111557 rows. the order of rows in 2 files is the same, so I just want to simply merge them, which means I would have one text file with 17 columns.

This is the first column of the 1st .txt file (they are tab limited)

```
     chr1   HAVANA  gene    29554   31109   .   +   .
```

This is the 1st line of the 2nd .txt file(they are tab limited)

```
     ENSG00000243485.2  ENSG00000243485.2   lincRNA NOVEL   MIR1302-11  lincRNA NOVEL   MIR1302-11
```

Comment: Please post one line from each file, and the corresponding desired line in the output file. What are the columns separated by?

Comment: Ok, this is just too much. Did you try to google anything? Do you have any of your own code? Even a line to open a file? To read lines from the file? To write a line to a file? When you have those, we can talk.

Comment: I haz a feeling that OP [copy-pasted an email reply](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27712062/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file1') as infile1, open('path/to/file2') as infile2, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row1,row2 in zip(csv.reader(infile1, delimiter='\t'), csv.reader(infile2, delimiter='\t')):
        writer.writerow(row1+row2)
```

Comment: @ali: this is exactly why I posted a comment for clarification on your original post. Please address that, without which I can't provide a super-accurate answer

Comment: @ali: I've updated my answer to be exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2, open('outfile','w') as out:
    for x in f1:
        y = next(f2)
        out.write("{}\t{}".format(x.strip(),y))
```

try like this if you getting error in above:

```
f1 = open('file1') 
f2 = open('file2')
out = open('outfile','w')
for x in f1:
    y = next(f2)
    out.write(x.strip() + "\t" + y)
```

Comment: I like it, but this only works if OP's files are space delimited, which is similar to the assumption I made. The question really isn't super clear

Comment: @  Hackaholic  my files are tab limited

Comment: gives this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax  and it is related to "," after f1

Comment: with open('fisrts.txt') as f1, open('eights.txt') as f2, open('outfile.txt','w') as out:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ali check the next version of solution